# Vue cli code not running ine the command prompt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, command-line-interface, vuex, vue-cli-3

Trying out vue cli for the first time and I can't get to open the code from the command-prompt line into my visual studio through the cd my-app code ., command, I can only access it through the vue ui interface but them my localhost page goes, and there is no way of debugging/checking the process of the project or at least I haven't found it yet, and before I install extensions etc I just want to make sure which one and to see if  there is a way to be checking your progress as you do when building in the browser...

Waiting for suggestions and

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed `Node.js` on your computer?

Otherwise it sounds like you don't have the correct path on your command line to run the vue project.

Try the following: Navigate to the project folder on your explorer. Press `Shift + right click` to open the powershell. type: `code .`

This opens the project folder in your IDE. Now open your terminal and type: `npm serve` or `yarn serve`

What happens?

Comment: That was the issue outdated version of node.js